# Nest API, what are STRING1 and STRING2 for

Tags: nest-api

On several of the fields in the nest api docs, I see examples with "STRING1" and "STRING2" in the URL which are described as "do not change", do I need to include those in requests, or what are those for?

[Example](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/api-overview#image_url-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, STRING1/2 are returned when you read the device values. You'll pass them along when you use the URL.

For example, when I read my camera, I get this response:

```
"image_url": "https://www.dropcam.com/api/wwn.get_image/CjZRcWll.../OwKxchf...?auth=c.twC2qlu...",
```

In this example, `STRING1 = CjZRcWll...` and `DEVICE_ID = OwKxchf`

I can copy the "`https://...`" string, paste it into a web browser and see the image that was captured.